# Помогите разобраться в задаче. Есть два вопроса

Tags: c++

> Таблица заполняется по следующему алгоритму:
> В таблицу вносятся все натуральные числа по порядку. 1 становится в левую
> верхнюю ячейку, затем выбирается самая левая незаполненная ячейка в
> самой первой строке таблицы и заполняется. Затем, пока у последней
> заполненной ячейки сосед слева существует и заполнен, опускаемся вниз и
> заполняем очередную ячейку. Когда же не окажется соседа слева, то
> начинается заполнение клеток справа налево. После того как будет заполнена
> ячейка в первом столбце, После этого алгоритм заполнения повторятся.
> Необходимо вывести строку и столбец в котором будет находится число,
> введенное с клавиатуры.

1. Как определить размер массива, если мы знаем только число, введенное пользователем?
2. В целом алгоритм решения я понял, но как вывести эту самую таблицу на экран? Значения ведь не по порядку идут.

Comment: таблица незаполненная? тогда получается заполнение идет змейкой?

Comment: В каком-то смысле так, нарисуй поймешь

Answer (score 2):

Массив и сама таблица не нужны. Заполнение бесконечной таблицы идет уголками, так что можно посчитать, сколько чисел содержат один квадратик, второй квадратик и так далее, и решить обратную задачу - к какому по очереди уголку принадлежит данное число, потом определить- вертикали его или горизонтали оно принадлежит, и вывести строку и столбец

```
1  2  5 ......
4  3  6 
9  8  7
.....
```

Например, число 6 принадлежит третьему по счёту уголку, поскольку оно больше, чем 2^2

Comment: Как это, уголками?

Comment: нарисуй поймешь ;)

Comment: @geralt Ну что, в принципе решения разобрались? Подсказки по реализации нужны?

Comment: да, разобрался, спасибо!